# Populate dropdownlist from database in asp.net MVC in a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Ok, I found some similar posts, but I don't find a way to solve it without a little help (the other posts have incomplete dates).

I have a page where I need to display a dropdownlist with values from database (display Name, but keeping the key Id as value).... this list, with other types of input for a form.

My Model:

```
public class AddOfferAnnounceModel
{
    public AnnounceTypeList AnnounceTypeList {get; set; }
    public int Surface { get; set; }
    public int SubTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 0)]
    public string AnnounceDetails { get; set; }

    public bool Net { get; set; }
}

public class AnnounceTypeList
{
    public int SubTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeDesc { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller [httpGET] Action (where probably must populate the dropdownlist:

```
// GET: Announce/Add new announce
    public ActionResult AddOffer()
    {
        string sql = "select typeId, typeDesc from announceTypes where parentTypeId = 1";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            var apartmentTypeList = new List<AnnounceTypeList>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                var apartmentType = new AnnounceTypeList
                {
                    SubTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TypeId"]),
                    TypeDesc = dr["TypeDesc"].ToString()
                };
                apartmentTypeList.Add(apartmentType);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My Controller [httpPOST] - where are all values returned from View and the query to insert into database

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOffer(AddOfferAnnounceModel model)
    {
        bool isValid = true; // daca datele introduse in formularul anuntului sunt corecte si respecta regulile

        if (isValid)
        {
            string announceDetailsItem = model.AnnounceDetails;
            decimal priceItem = model.Price;
            int surfaceItem = model.Surface;
            int subTypeId = model.SubTypeId; // GETTING FROM DROPDOWNLIST !!!!
            int netItem = Convert.ToInt32(model.Net);
            DateTime dateItem = DateTime.Now;

            string sql = "insert into announces (typeid, statusId, locationId, finalPrice, date, surface, net, announceDetails) values (1, 1, 1, " + priceItem + ",'" + dateItem + "'," + surfaceItem + "," + netItem + ",'" + announceDetailsItem + "')";
                  sql += " insert into announceOfferApartments (announceId, subTypeId, yPersonTypeId) values ((select max(announceId) from announces), 6, 4)";

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text
                };
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return RedirectToAction("OfferList", "Announce");
                // daca datele au fost introduse in DB, se redirectioneaza catre Lista Anunturilor
            }
        }
        return OfferList();
    }
```

My View :

```
@model myApp.com.Models.AddOfferAnnounceModel
```

...

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surface, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surface, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
```

....

I know can't have more than one model in a View. I know that probably must create a Combined class which include all parameters, but I don't know how I must to populate a List from DataTable (or maybe a Dictionary with Key and Value ?!?) and display the Value in dropdown, and transfer the key to parameter subTypeId in Controller->ActionResult AddOffer[httpPost].

I need to create 4 5 dropdownlists in same form, but probably the method will be the same .... !

thanks, and hope to not receive too many negative votes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to create View Model which will hold the data that will be displayed in the drop down list and other data as well which will get posted back via `HttpPost`. Here are the steps to. First create a new class which would be View Model:

```
public class AddOfferViewModel
{

   public AddOfferAnnounceModel Model {get;set;}

   public SelectList AnnouncementTypeSelectList {get;set;}

   public AddOfferViewModel()
   {
       Model = new AddOfferAnnounceModel();
   }

}
```

and now in your Get action of Add Offer you will have to compose the ViewModel and pass it to the View:

```
// GET: Announce/Add new announce
public ActionResult AddOffer()
{
    string sql = "select typeId, typeDesc from announceTypes where parentTypeId = 1";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        var apartmentTypeList = new List<AnnounceTypeList>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            var apartmentType = new AnnounceTypeList
            {
                SubTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TypeId"]),
                TypeDesc = dr["TypeDesc"].ToString()
            };
            apartmentTypeList.Add(apartmentType);
        }

         AddOfferViewModel viewModel = new AddOfferViewModel();
         viewModel.AnnouncementTypeSelectList  = new SelectList(apartmentTypeList,"SubTypeId","TypeDesc")
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Now your view should be strongly type with the `AddOfferViewModel`:

```
@model myApp.com.ViewwModels.AddOfferViewModel
...
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.Surface, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.Surface, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and now you can add dropdown list like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Model.SubTypeId,Model.Model.AnnouncementTypeSelectList)
```

You can also do it other way which would be to add property in ViewModel to hold `List<AnnouncementType>` and then in View inside the `DropDownListFor` method call create `SelectList` inline.

In that case, replace property:

```
public SelectList AnnouncementTypeSelectList {get;set;}
```

with :

```
public List<AnnounceTypeList> AnnouncementTypes {get;set;}
```

and in your action, you will just set the `AnnouncementTypes` now like:

```
// GET: Announce/Add new announce
public ActionResult AddOffer()
{
    string sql = "select typeId, typeDesc from announceTypes where parentTypeId = 1";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        var apartmentTypeList = new List<AnnounceTypeList>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            var apartmentType = new AnnounceTypeList
            {
                SubTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TypeId"]),
                TypeDesc = dr["TypeDesc"].ToString()
            };
            apartmentTypeList.Add(apartmentType);
        }

         AddOfferViewModel viewModel = new AddOfferViewModel();
         viewModel.AnnouncementTypes = apartmentTypeList ;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

and in View for creating dropdown, it will be the following line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Model.SubTypeId,
                            new SelectList(Model.Model.AnnouncementTypes,
                                           "SubTypeId",
                                           "TypeDesc"))
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: thanks. forget to write construct AnnouncementTypes in AddOfferAnnounceModel class :D now it's work perfect, and save the value in AddOffer [httpPost]

Comment: Glad that it helped,  feel free to mark post as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 properties to your view model, one of type  `List<SelectListItem>` to pass the options neeeded for your SELECT element and one for the selected value.

```
public class AddOfferAnnounceModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { set;get;}  // These 2 properties for the dropdown
    [Required]
    public int SelectedItem { set;get;}

    public int Surface { get; set; }    
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }    
    public string AnnounceDetails { get; set; }

    public bool Net { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you can create an object of your `AddOfferAnnounceModel`, populate the `Items` property and pass that to the view. There is no need to use `DataTable`. Use the SqlReader as all you care about is, reading the result once.

```
public ActionResult AddOffer()
{
   var vm = new AddOfferAnnounceModel();
   vm.Items = GetItems();
   return View(vm);
}
public List<SelectListItem> GetItems()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var sql = "select TypeId, TypeDesc from announceTypes where parentTypeId = 1";
    var conStr = @"yourConnectionStringGoesHere";
    using (var c = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (r.HasRows)
                {
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        var t = new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Value = r.GetInt32(r.GetOrdinal("TypeId")).ToString(),
                            Text = r.GetString(r.GetOrdinal("TypeDesc"))
                        };
                        list.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

In the view, which is strongly typed to the `AddOfferAnnounceModel` class, you can use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper

```
@model AddOfferAnnounceModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Price)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Surface)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.AnnounceDetails)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.SelectedItem,Model.Items)
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action, when the form is submitted, the selected option value will be in the `SelectedItem` property

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOffer(AddOfferAnnounceModel model)
{
     // check model.SelectedItem and use that for saving
}
```

If you have more dropdowns, you will do the same thing (add 2 properties, one for the list and one for selected value and populate the list property and use the `DropDownListFor` helper.

I would also suggest **to not do string concatenation for your insert query for saving the new record**. That approach is prone to SQL Injection attacks. Take a look at `SqlParameters` and how to use that to pass your different params for your query. [This post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection) explains various approach to handle that

Comment: thanks for your reply. I used the method from previous post.  And thanks for your advice about sql injection ...I'll try to be prudent with it.