# how to show a dropdownlist in razor using mysql in vs17

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using mysql connection in my webApp and I want to display a dropdownlist from a table in mysql.

this is my controller action.

```
   public ActionResult AddRegion()
   {
        var connection = db.Connections.FirstOrDefault();
        string connStr = "server=" + connection.IpAddress + ";user=" + connection.UserName + ";database=" + connection.DatabaseName + ";port=" + connection.PortNumber + ";password=" + connection.Password + ";SslMode=none;";
        string query = "select * from Cities";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

        return View();
    }
```

this is my razor

```
  @using(Html.BeginForm("AddRegion", "Index", FormMethod.Post))
  {
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label col-md-2">City Name</label>
             <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" name="CityName" value="" />
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Region Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" name="regionName" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label col-md-2">Region Code</label>
             <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" name="regionCode" value="" />
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
             </div>
          </div>
  }
```

I have No model in top
And I want City Name Part be dropdownlist.
thanks for the help

Comment: Take a look for these examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613851/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-from-database), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479719/populate-dropdownlist-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-in-a-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247871/binding-to-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc3). You can use `ViewBag` to populate `<option>` tags.

Comment: You can use fill dropdown list via using ajax.